# Probability that an item from a group is not in a random sample (sampling without replacement)

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory

I have a dataset of $3600$ items. There are $120$ item groups, each containing $30$ items. I create a test set by randomly sampling $720$ items without replacement from the dataset. What is the probability that there is at least one item of every item group in the sampled set?

And what is the probability that at least $x$ item groups are not in the sampled set? (any combination of item groups, not specific item groups)

Thanks a lot to the efforts of [Gabriel Romon](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4812287/915357) and [RyRy The Fly Guy](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4811720/915357).

**Extra info**:

Brute forcing leads to a result of about $0.865$

Initially, I started with a easy approach that said: Every item group has the same probability of being sampled, so let's dumb it down to sampling from 120 item groups with equal probability. But obviously that does not work, as it would sample $\frac{720}{30} = 24$ item groups and ignores that every item group can be sampled.

Comment: I remember a similar problem out of the Sheldon Ross probability book where you had to evaluate a dozen terms of inclusion-exclusion to get the answer.  Surely there is an Einstein among us who can see a simpler path....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Label the groups $G_1,\ldots,G_{120}$.
You're looking for
$$P(\bigcap_{i=1}^{120} \text{at least one item from }G_i) 
= 1-P(\bigcup_{i=1}^{120} \text{no item from }G_i).
$$
By the inclusion-exclusion principle, the probability of the union is
$$
\begin{aligned}
&\phantom{=}\sum_{i=1}^{120} (-1)^{i+1} \sum_{I\subset \{1,\ldots 120\},|I|=i} P(\bigcap_{g\in I} \text{no item from }G_g)
\\&= 
\sum_{i=1}^{120} (-1)^{i+1} \binom{120}i P(\bigcap_{g\in \{1,\ldots i\}} \text{no item from }G_g)
\end{aligned}$$

Note that $$
\begin{aligned}
P(\bigcap_{g\in \{1,\ldots i\}} \text{no item from }G_g) 
&= P(\text{all items sampled from groups } G_{i+1},\ldots,G_{120} ) 
\\&= \frac{\binom{(120-i)30}{720}}{\binom{3600}{720}}.
\end{aligned}
$$

Thus the probability is
$$1-\sum_{i=1}^{120} (-1)^{i+1} \binom{120}i \frac{\binom{(120-i)30}{720}}{\binom{3600}{720}} \approx 0.865166,$$
with the estimate being given by Mathematica.

This finding is corroborated by the following Python simulation:

```
arr = np.zeros((3600,2), dtype="int16")
arr[:,0] = np.arange(1,3601)
arr[:,1] = np.repeat(np.arange(1,121),30)

res = []
rep = 50000
for _ in range(rep):
    sample = arr[np.random.choice(arr.shape[0], 720, replace=False), :]
    res.append(len(set(sample[:,1])) == 120)
print(np.mean(np.array(res)))
```

which returned 0.86428 on my computer.

Comment: Thank you! This seems to correspond to my $0.135$ result too

Answer (score 3):

**What is the probability that there is at least one item of every item group in the sampled set?**

Let $S$ be the sample space consisting of all possible test sets. Then, $|S|$ corresponds to all possible ways of choosing $720$ objects from a group of $3600$ objects. Hence, $|S| = { 3600 \choose 720 }$.

Let $E$ be an event consisting of every test set such that there is at least one item from every item group in that test set. Since items are randomly sampled, each test set is equally likely to occur. This implies the probability of $E$ is given by

$$ P(E) = \frac{|E|}{|S|} $$

Note that $E = (E^C)^C = S \cap (E^C)^C = S - E^C$, implying $|E| = |S - E^C| = |S| - |E^C|$. In other words, we can find $|E|$ by counting the number of test sets in the complement of $E$, denoted by $|E^C|$, and subtracting this quantity from $|S|$. So, by substitution we have

$$ P(E) = \frac{|E|}{|S|} = \frac{|S|-|E^C|}{|S|} = 1 - \frac{|E^C|}{|S|} = 1 - \frac{1}{|S|} |E^C| $$

Now, formally speaking we have

$$ E = \Big\{T \in S: \bigwedge_{i=1}^{120} \exists x \Big[ x \in G_i \wedge x \in T \Big] \Big\} $$

where $T$ is an abitrary test set in $S$; $x$ is a variable representing an arbitrary item; and $G_i$ is the $i$th item group. Hence,

$
\begin{array}{lll}
E^C & = \Big\{T \in S: \bigwedge_{i=1}^{120} \exists x \Big[ x \in G_i \wedge x \in T \Big] \Big\}^C \\
& = \Big\{T \in S: \neg \Big( \bigwedge_{i=1}^{120} \exists x \Big[ x \in G_i \wedge x \in T \Big] \Big) \Big\} & \text{by definition of complement} \\
& = \Big\{T \in S: \bigvee_{i=1}^{120} \neg \exists x \Big[ x \in G_i \wedge x \in T \Big] \Big\} & \text{by DeMorgan's Law} \\
& = \Big\{T \in S: \bigvee_{i=1}^{120} \forall x \neg \Big[ x \in G_i \wedge x \in T \Big] \Big\} & \text{by DeMorgan's Law for quantifiers} \\
& = \Big\{T \in S: \bigvee_{i=1}^{120} \forall x \Big[ \neg(x \in G_i) \vee \neg(x \in T) \Big] \Big\} & \text{by DeMorgan's Law} \\
& = \Big\{T \in S: \bigvee_{i=1}^{120} \forall x \Big[ x \notin G_i \vee x \notin T \Big] \Big\} & \text{by definition of $\notin$} \\
& = \bigcup_{i=1}^{120} \Big\{T \in S: \forall x \Big[ x \notin G_i \vee x \notin T \Big] \Big\} & \text{by definition of $\cup$} \\
& = \bigcup_{i=1}^{120} \Big\{T \in S: \text{no items in $G_i$ are in $T$} \Big\} \\
\end{array}
$

When I initially responded to OP, I erroneously concluded $\{T \in S: \text{no items in $G_i$ are in $T$} \} \cap \{T \in S: \text{no items in $G_j$ are in $T$} \} = \emptyset$ for all $i,j$. In other words, I believed all test sets having no items from group $i$ was *disjoint* from all test sets having no items from group $j$ for all $i,j$. Of course, this is untrue and I overcounted test sets in $E^C$ as a result. This came to my attention after @GabrielRomon indicated something was amiss. The truth is each pairwise intersection of such sets is *not* disjoint, so we find $|E^C| = \Big|\bigcup_{i=1}^{120} \Big\{T \in S: \text{no items in $G_i$ are in $T$} \Big\}\Big|$ by the [inclusion-exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) as follows

$$ \Big| E^C \Big| = \sum_{I \in \mathcal{P}(\{1,2,...,120\})-\emptyset} (-1)^{|I|+1} \Big| \bigcap_{i \in I} \Big\{T: \text{no items in $G_i$ are in $T$} \} \Big| $$

The number of subsets of $\{1,2,...,120\}$ consisting of any $k$ indices is ${120 \choose k}$ for $k=1,2,...,120$, and the number of test sets having no items from any collection of $k$ item groups is ${3600-30k \choose 720}$. The latter quantity is derived by counting the number of ways we can randomly select $720$ items from the $3600-30k$ items left over after we forbid ourselves to select the $30k$ items belonging to the $k$ groups we don't want in the sample. Hence, the above equation becomes

$$ |E^C| = \sum_{k=1}^{120} (-1)^{k+1} {120 \choose k} {3600-30k \choose 720} $$

and since for $k > 96$ we have $3600-30k < 720$ and ${3600-30k \choose 720} = 0$, we have

$$ |E^C| = \sum_{k=1}^{96} (-1)^{k+1} {120 \choose k} {3600-30k \choose 720} $$

You can now compute the probability of $E$ as follows

$$ P(E) = 1- \frac{1}{|S|} |E^C| = 1 - \frac{1}{{3600 \choose 720}} \sum_{k=1}^{96} (-1)^{k+1} {120 \choose k} {3600-30k \choose 720} \\ \approx 1 - \frac{512490315887935410017631 \cdot 10^{756}}{3800901634398358932885052 \cdot 10^{756}} \approx 1 - 0.134834 = 0.865166 $$

This calculation was performed [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Sum%5B%5C%2840%29120%20choose%20k%5C%2841%29%5C%2840%29%5C%2840%293600-30k%5C%2841%29%20choose%20720%5C%2841%29Power%5B%5C%2840%29-1%5C%2841%29%2Ck%2B1%5D%2C%7Bk%2C1%2C96%7D%5D), [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=3600%20choose%20720), and [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Divide%5B512490315887935410017631%2C3800901634398358932885052%5D) with Wolfram Alpha.

**What is the probability that at least $x$ item groups are not in the sampled set (any combination of item groups, not specific item groups)?**

Let $E'$ be an event consisting of every test set for which at least $x$ item groups are not in the test set. Then, using the same reasoning  above we can derive

$$ P(E') = \frac{1}{{3600 \choose 720}} \sum_{k=x}^{96} (-1)^{k+1} {120 \choose k} {3600-30k \choose 720} $$

Comment: Would you mind to confirm your result of $0.15418$ is $(1-\frac{|E^C|}{|S|})$, or $\frac{|E^C|}{|S|}$ ? Thanks.

Comment: Great catch! i forgot about the $1- ...$ it has been corrected. thanks

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation! Something seems not to be right: If my test set has the size of 120, I get a result of $-1.63792 \cdot 10^{14}$. I edited my question to include the code to calculate it in Python

Comment: I think something is amiss in your reasoning, the true probability seems to be $\approx 0.865166$.

Comment: So i figured out what went wrong... I incorrectely assumed all test sets having no items from goup $i$ is *disjoint* from all test sets having no items from group $j$ over all $i,j$. @GabrielRomon thank you for alerting me that something was amiss. The inclusion-exclusion principle is indeed the way to proceed here. I have updated my answer to reflect this. I'm glad we got this sorted out!